# help on vimperator tabcompletion

Tags: firefox, autocomplete, vimperator

I am a vim user. I installed the vimperator add on for firefox recently. I love it. But I am stuck up with the autocomplete of urls. How do i walk through (or choose) from the list of autocomplete results?. I looked for the answer but could not find it. Can someone help me?. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press (shift)TAB to cycle through them.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to set

wildoptions=auto

That will show all the possible completions as you cycle through them.

Answer (score 0):

```
cnoremap <C-o> <S-Tab>
cnoremap <C-i> <Tab>
" <Tab> and <S-tab> is not typing-friendly, whereas if you use left palm to press <Ctrl> 
"+ or <CapsLock> as <Ctrl>, <C-i> and <C-o> is superb for completion, and also compliant to 
"+ normal mode <C-i> <C-o> which navigate browser history, thus strength you muscle memory.
```

and further,

```
cnoremap <C-j> <Down>
cnoremap <C-k> <Up>
" if you have cmdline history 'source ~/.vimperatorrc', you could type ':' (or simply ';'
"+ if you have swap them as below says), then type 'so' then press <C-k>, which 
"+ bring your old history.  "+ this relys on an easy-typing left ctrl, too.
```

and more,

```
cnoremap <C-l> <End>
cnoremap [ <Left>
cnoremap ] <right>
cnoremap <C-n> <C-Left>
cnoremap <C-p> <C-right>
nnoremap ; :
" these keymap could be rather controversial, 
"+ you may try them out to see if they suits you or not.
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation and guidance on where these commands should be used?

Comment: some explanation added .